# How to check if table is already joined using same columns in Laravel Query Builder

Tags: php, laravel, join

I have found a [half answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54902510/how-to-check-if-table-is-already-joined-in-laravel-query-builder/54902511) here to my question.

Using Laravel 11, I dynamically test for a $query instance to see if the current table about to be joined is using already listed in the joins:

```
function isJoined($query, $table){
    $joins = collect($query->getQuery()->joins);
    return $joins->pluck('table')->contains($table);
}
```

But a table in my DB could be joined multiple times in a query subject to the table it is joining to. For example in my DB I have the following 3 tables:

```
properties
hotels
addresses
```

The relations are:

```
properties morphOne addresses.
properties belongsTo hotels. 
hotels morphOne addresses.
```

Both properties and hotels have a morph

I want to join the properties table to addresses (for standalone properties) and join the properties table to hotels then to addresses again (for properties that are rooms in a hotel, so the hotel's address is used):

```
properties -> addresses (joined on property.id = addresses.addressable_id and addressable_type = 'App\Models\Property')

properties -> hotels (joined on properties.id = hotels.id)

hotel -> addresses (joined on hotel.id = addresses.addressable_id and addressable_type = 'App\Models\Hotel')
```

How do I check that a table join exists (my code does this already), using the same columns as the new join?

In my example, the properties table joining to addresses is a different join to properties table joining to hotels then hotels to addresses (the second address join is on hotels so valid).

How do I confirm the join does not exist when it is matched by tables being joined and columns used to join them?